# Resizing images to fit smaller browsers

Tags: javascript, image, browser, resize, resolution

I've been searching the questions here for weeks and haven't found an answer to this, so here it goes:

I created a fairly large image (800x1000px) to be displayed in the center of my site. I made it so large with large screen resolutions in mind but I've been using the CSS `max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;`
to  have it resize proportionally to fit on computers with smaller screen resolutions as well. (keep in mind this is **not** a "background" image)

However, what I'd really like, is for the image to resize **only** when keeping it at the current size would create a horizontal scrolling bar in the user's browser. However, if it will only make a **vertical scrolling bar**, I'd like it to **not resize** the image, that way it can be as large as possible (the reason being that I feel a horizontal scroll is less professional looking than a vertical scroll as most sites have a vertical scroll anyway).

Is there a way to accomplish this with CSS or will I need Javascript? And if I'll need javascript please spell out the code as I have absolutely no experience with javascript, thanks!

Comment: Please create a JSfiddle demonstrating the problem, I'm not sure I understand you right.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Java` is not `JavaScript`.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes As far as I understood, he wants to resize only if the image would overlap the sides (thus creating a horizontal scrollbar). Vertical scrollbar would be alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `max-height: 100%`, leaving only the `max-width: 100%`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KKMxb/)

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: No need for `height: auto;`.